# raphael how to move a curve shape

Tags: javascript, text, raphael

I just wanted to ask i got a curve and i want to move it up but not sure if iam doing it correctly. I have made it below and set the color to orange.

```
    var curvePath = paper.path("M690,124s20,15 10,19Z");
    curvePath.attr({fill:"orange"});
```

Here i have tried to make it move up but iam not sure iam suppose to be using m or z.

```
    var anim = Raphael.animation({y: 10 , x: 700}, 10000)
    curvePath.animate(anim.delay(5000));
```

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
var c = paper.path("M10 10L90 90");
c.attr({fill:"orange"}); 
c.animate({'path' : {M: 10 , Z: 700}}, 10000);
```

You do not move paths on `x`, `y` . You mode them along a path.

***EDIT: (after comments)***

```
var curvePath = paper.path("M320,124s20,15 10,19Z"); 
curvePath.attr({fill:"orange"});
curvePath.animate({'path' : "M320,24s20,15 10,19Z"}, 10000);
```

Comment: That dose work however, with my old code the curve which i had drawn had color inside of it. So you could see the orange in this one its just a line. Also as its moving it gets smaller. I just need it to move up. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: check my update to suite your needs. This is my first time trying raphaeljs. So, if it doesnt work, bear with me. I am using [playground](http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html) to help you. Try it :)